# Using a Wii/PS3 guitar heroes guitar on a PS3/Wii console

Tags: ps3, nintendo-wii, controllers, guitar-hero

I'd like to know if there's any way to use a Wii guitar (drumset, etc.) on a PS3 - or a PS3 guitar on a Wii.

Do I need any adapters?

Answer (score 3):

For the wireless controllers, there's no cross compatibility between consoles.  Each console uses a specific protocol to connect, and they don't talk to each other.

For USB wired controllers, it's likely possible with a 3rd party adapter, but each controller has console-specific buttons, so I don't know how that would work exactly.  For instance, my Xbox drum set has an "Xbox" button on the face of it.

Heck, the Wii Guitar Hero World Tour drums and guitar don't even work with Rock Band [*on the Wii*](http://www.joystiq.com/Instrument-Compatibility-Matrix/) - getting them to work with another console's games is right out.

As you pointed out (?) there's a Datel adapter available that adapts the Wii Guitar Hero Guitar (supposedly) to RockBand on the Wii and on the PS3, but people have had very [mixed to negative](http://www.rockband.com/forums/showthread.php?t=146620&page=1) results with it.

Comment: so what is [THIS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSrnGQwJq3Y) ... ? lol

Comment: Something I was unaware of :)  That's the trouble with trying to find out if something exists - if it does and it's common, great!

Comment: Indeed, there are both good and bad comments about it, that's why I asked here to know if anyone had any idea about any other device / adaptater or so ...

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't know of a way to use PS# guitar on Wii and vice versa, I was able to use a a wired Guitar Hero guitar for the PS2, the one that came with the first Guitar Hero, on both the PS3 and Wii, though both require adapters.

I have used [this adapter for the PS3](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/ps2-to-ps3-usb-controller-adapter-converter-22cm-30475) and [this adapter for the Wii](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/playstation-2-ps2-to-wii-controller-adapter-13-5cm-cable-23206), though I'm pretty sure there are other compatible adapters.

Answer (score 0):

ANY Rock Band or Guitar Hero instrument that uses a dongle rather then a factory controller is interchangeable. Guitar hero controllers are harder to interchange then Harmonix, but not impossible. To use them on consoles other then originally designated requires soldering. Harmonix instruments simply have a jumper near the microcontroller to determine which system the instrument is for.  This is true with ALL HARMONIX. Possibly those Red Octane controllers using a dongle as well. The simple fact is, if you search the web, everyone says no, not interchangeable, they don't speak the same language, bla bla. While this is true for non-dongle GUITAR HERO controllers, it is not for ROCK BAND, and those with a dongle. Here's why. The dongles were not made by Nintendo, Sony, or Microsoft. They were made by Harmonix and/or Red Octane. Therefore, they are not proprietary and unique to each system, and DO speak the same language across the board. The instruments that used the factory controller(wiimote, sixaxxis, xbox) to interface with the console generally are not really interchanged. Open a Harmonix controller, and look for a bubble of solder near the edge of the board labeled J1 - J1.5. Bridging one side is ps3, bridging the other is Wii. That simple! If you have any questions, send me an email. `[redacted]`.